# Drag and drop El Capitan Safari bookmark to delete it,but cursor consistent shows close button

Tags: safari, macos, cursor

[image: Cursor has problem]
This problem random happened.I don't touch any settings it happened when I first installed El Capitan.

Comment: The X should disappear after a second or 2, then let go.

Comment: It consistent appear,unless I click.